# Facebook JavaScript SDK loading issue

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk

I copy/paste code (with minor adjustments) from facebook APIs site and it is not loading. This is code :

```
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'xxx',                        // App ID from the app dashboard
      channelUrl : 'channel.html', // Channel file for x-domain comms
      status     : true,                                 // Check Facebook Login status
      xfbml      : true                                  // Look for social plugins on the page
    });

    // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here
    alert('inited');
  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

I am trying to use it on Android PhoneGap app, but it is not working on my browser too. 
Why is it happening?

Comment: Do you mean that it is not working in the Android app, and also in your web browser? Are there any error messages?

Comment: No, it is not working on Android and desktop.On Android there is no errors, but on desktop I got this : Failed to load resource

Comment: Which browser is having the problem? All browsers? One specific? Do you have any developer tools installed on your browser? If not, you should. In the developer tools check out the debugging, console, network results. Anything that can help you find out what is going on.

Comment: On Chrome it gives me error Failed to load resource and in network script is red and no response. Same on Firefox